# Limit parallelism of an Async method and not block a Thread-Pool thread

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have an asynchronous method `RequestInternalAsync()` which makes requests to an external resource, and want to write a wrapper method which limits a number of concurrent asynchronous requests to the method by reducing parallelism.

First option, that comes to mind is a `TaskScheduler` with limited concurrency (`LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`, `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` etc.).

But to run a task with a custom scheduler, I have to start the task using a `TaskFactory` which accepts only `Action<>`, i.e. I cannot do it by not blocking an extra thread for just waiting for execution of inner method.

Second option is `SemaphoreSlim`, it does its job, but in this case I'm implementing throttling myself, instead of using a `TaskScheduler`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // TESTING 1

    var task1 = Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => RequestAsyncBad()));

    task1.Wait();

    // TESTING 2

    var task2 = Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => RequestAsyncBetter()));

    task2.Wait();
}

private static Task RequestInternalAsync()
{
    return Task.Delay(500);
}
```

**Solution #1:**

```
private static readonly ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair _concurrentPair
    = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(TaskScheduler.Default, 2);

public static Task RequestAsyncBad()
{
    // Dumb: Because TaskFactory doesn't provide an overload which accepts another task, only action.
    // As result, we blocking a thread to just wait until the inner task finishes.

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RequestInternalAsync().Wait(),
        CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, _concurrentPair.ConcurrentScheduler);
}
```

**Solution #2 (better):**

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2);

public static async Task RequestAsyncBetter()
{
    // Here we don't waste thread-pool thread on waiting for a completion of inner task,
    // but instead of using TaskScheduler, implementing a hand-made stuff with semaphore. 

    await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    try
    {
        await RequestInternalAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

**What is the more elegant way to do this?**

- to reuse standard `Task` API of TPL and `TaskScheduler`
- and not block an extra thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TaskScheduler` is only useful for CPU-bound work. Your work is not using threads. It uses IO completion ports which means that your network call does not hold any threads at all. There is no way to involve a `TaskScheduler` for an IO operation.

If you're not yet convinced: Async IO in .NET is based on using `TaskCompletionSource` which is not bound to threads or schedulers in the slightest way.

`SemaphoreSlim` is the right way to do it. Or, create a `ServicePoint` and set its maximum concurrency. Only applicable for `HTTP` requests.

Note, that if you find yourself using `Wait` you should hesitate and think about what you're doing. Often, this is a mistake.

Comment: Thanks! So, as I understand, `TaskScheduler`s only responsible *WHEN* and *WHERE* to start a task, but not designed to control life-time of the started task?

Comment: I would not say that. Note, that there are two kinds of tasks (and this is confusing!): CPU-work (a task backed by a delegate that eventually runs) and "other work" backed by TaskCompletionSource. Only the first case uses TaskScheduler (and it always uses one). So I'd say that a TaskScheduler is responsible for completing a task that is backed by a delegate by running the delegate when and where it sees fit.

Comment: Neither is it possible to give TCS a scheduler not does the TPL ever ask one to execute a TCS-based task.; I believe that understanding this point is quite enlightening when working with the TPL.

Comment: +1. I've recently started using the terms "Delegate Task" and "Promise Task" to distinguish the different types of tasks. Not saying that everyone has to use that terminology, but it may be helpful when discussing the difference.

Comment: @StephenCleary The problem for me was that I haven't found any source of information where it could be explained what `TaskScheduler`s are designed for, and why `TaskFactory` intentionally accepts only delegates. Thanks for your comment. I really like reading your blog, and looking forward to read your book when it comes to Kindle :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task RequestAsyncCool()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            await RequestInternalAsync();
        },
        CancellationToken.None, 
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
        TaskScheduler.Current);
}
```

You really shouldn't `Wait` for Tasks. See https://www.google.com/search?q=task+wait+deadlock

Did you look into [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It might be just the thing for you...

Comment: The problem here is that if I place an asynchronous method into `Task.Factory.StartNew` which accepts `Func<Task>`, and limit concurrency by specifying a custom `TaskScheduler`, then concurrency limit will only work for a first part of my async methods, it won't wait until the first 2 methods finished before starting new methods (2 is my limit of parallelism). That's why I had to place `Wait()` there, and that's why I disliked this and asked this question :)